# Image transformation where a curve becomes a straight line

Tags: image-processing, matlab, transform

Suppose that I have the green curve (image attached for visualization), values stored in a vector and I want to transform the image such that the curve becomes a *straight horizontal* line. So if the curve becomes a straight line all normals of the curve has to be parallel to the vertical axis.

How can I achieve such a transformation?

[image: Picture drawn for visualzation]

Comment: Does the problem have any constraints? There is an infinitude of such transformations.

Comment: No not really, only that the line has to be straightend. Why do we have infinite transformations then?

Comment: If a map $f(x,y)$ applies to the entire image, but needs only straighten a curve on that image without constraints on how it alters the rest of the image, the values of $f$ for the $(x,y)$ that correspond to points *not* on the curve can be anything at all. I'm pretty sure I can even prove an infinitude of everywhere-differentiable maps that meet your needs, as long as your curve is differentiable.

Comment: Could one constraint be that parallel lines remain parallel i.e when I have multiple curves just with a offset on the vertical axis, the transformation would preserve the parallelity. If not could you give me an concrete example with an additional constraint such that the transformation becomes unique?

Comment: Give more constraints, there are too many transforms that can be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift each pixel column so that the slice of the green line in that column is centered at a certain vertical coordinate. Like Mack says there are plenty of other transforms but perhaps this one satisfies the constraints you try to describe.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a grid transform. Each point of the grid has a $(dx,dy)$ offset, and a point in the middle of a square is interpolated according to the control points. Specifically in your case, you can keep most of the points in place, except those which are near the curve you want to straighten.

[image]